Error, when trying to save file on harddrive
With the code below, objwkb.close works for me,
Set rs= currentDB. Openrecordset("dynamic_query", opensnapshot)

Set objxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objwkb = objxl.workbook.add

With objwkb.Worksheets(1)
   .cells(1,1).copyfromrecordset rs
End with

 objwkb.saveas filename:="h:\aaa\bb\output.xls"

Objxl.quit
Set objxl = nothing

Instead of the .saveas file, the line below works, but that forces me to manually type the file and path.
Objwkb.close savechanges:=True
I get an error 1004, meaning the saveas method could not be executed.

Yeah, sorry. It's error 1004. I've updated that above.

...currentDB. Openrecordset... works for you? With a space in between. Do you use an ancient version of office that can only save .xls, or do you need a parameter to specify the file type?

I have to dig deep in memory, but I might recall a .SaveAs2 function to specify the filename.

@hennep.. Code works for me . No space in between.. Sorry, I wrote it with my mobile, so excuse that typo.

Error 1004 can indicate an error in the path. Are you sure h:\aaa\bb\ exists?
Also, you need to specify the file format:
    objwkb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\temp\output.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

or
    objwkb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\temp\output.xls", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal

In MS-Access you might need:
    Const xlWorkbookNormal = -4143
    Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51


Yes the path exists, and I have the necessary permission. When I use " objwkb.close savechanges:=true" I deliberately chose the same path, and it works... Just not with.saveas

I added the constant -4143, I believe that was the only difference. It seemed to think a little longer, but I got the same error 1004..saveas method of the workbook object could not be executed.

I wouldn't be surprised if the H: drive is on OneDrive. Try a different approach, save it somewhere else and move it with: Name "...\somewhere\output.xls" As "H:\aaa\bb\output.xls"

No, or didn't change anything. One thing I do notice is that VBA doesn't recognise ".Saveas" as a method. It doesn't convert automatically to the capital S and A, which it would do it it recognised SaveAs as a method.

You didn't declare objwkb, so it is a Variant by default. With early binding: Dim objwkb As Excel.Application it might detect the method. That also needs a reference. I don't expect that to solve the issue of saving the file

The above is wrong, objwbk should not be the application object:
Dim objxl As Excel.Application
Dim objwkb As Excel.Workbook

despite
With the code below, objwkb.close works for me,
Set rs= currentDB. Openrecordset("dynamic_query", opensnapshot)
Set objxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")??! Ok I'll try defining/decorating it as such

It has a compiling problem with  dim objXL as excel. Application... Could it be in missing a reference?

Yes, with early binding it needs a reference to the "Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Library"

Well it's Access 2007. I have the Microsoft office 16.0 access database engine object library
